# How can I map Jooq with field joda.time.DateTime to a Pojo with java.time.Instant

Tags: java, jooq, jsonschema2pojo

I have **jooq** create TableImpl POJO name CONNECTOR with variable **joda.time.DateTime**

and **jsonschema2pojo** create POJO name JsonConnector with variable **java.time.Instant**

how to convert jooq select result fetch to jsonschema2pojo create obj

```
List <JsonConnector> list = ctx.select(
    CONNECTOR.INT1,
    CONNECTOR.STRING1,
    CONNECTOR.STRING2,
    CONNECTOR.STRING3,
    CONNECTOR.STRING4,
    CONNECTOR.JODA_TIME_DATETIME))
    .from(CONNECTOR)
    .fetchInto(JsonConnector.class);
```

**jooq** fetchInto jsonschema2pojo everything simple type convert is ok, but pojo type **org.joda.time.DateTime** to type **java.time.Instant**

that will throw exception
*org.jooq.exception.MappingException: An error ocurred when mapping record to class JsonConnector*

how can I write function like
`TableField<ConnectorRecord, Instant> convertDateTimeToInstant(TableField<ConnectorRecord, DateTime> datatimeField)`
or something good method

Thanks

Comment: What's the reason why you're using the Joda time library, when at the same time you're also using JSR 310 types?

Comment: I took over and maintained a project for a while. It ran very well with jOOQ and DateTime, and we had lots of functions to manipulate DateTime and strings. We received a new request regarding a JSON issue, so I used jsonschema2pojo. When you asked me, I suddenly realized that I had misunderstood and thought jOOQ could only work with DateTime. I changed "<userType>org.joda.time.LocalDate</userType>" to "<userType>java.time.Instant</userType>" and it ran smoothly.

Comment: but, if I change jooq forcedType from DateTime to Instant, our original code must modify lots. so back to my question, can we have other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Register a global `ConverterProvider`

For the particular use-case you have here, you can implement a [`ConverterProvider`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/fetching/converter-provider/) that is able to convert between these two data types. `ConverterProvider` is an SPI that allows to override the default data type conversions between two data types, such as `DateTime` and `Instant`, in both directions.

Roughly:

```java
class MyConverterProvider implements ConverterProvider {
    final ConverterProvider delegate = new DefaultConverterProvider();
    
    @Override
    public <T, U> Converter<T, U> provide(Class<T> tType, Class<U> uType) {
        if (tType == DateTime.class && uType == Instant.class) {
            return Converter.ofNullable(tType, uType,
                t -> (U) dateTimeToInstant((DateTime) t),
                u -> (T) instantToDateTime((Instant) u)
            );
        }
        
        // Delegate all other type pairs to jOOQ's default
        else
            return delegate.provide(tType, uType);
    }
}
```

You then set that to your local or global `Configuration`:

```java
configuration.set(new MyConverterProvider());
```

#### Using a local ad-hoc converter

You can always attach a local [ad-hoc converter](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/fetching/ad-hoc-converter/) to a field, effectively chaining converters

```java
List <JsonConnector> list = ctx.select(
    CONNECTOR.INT1,
    CONNECTOR.STRING1,
    CONNECTOR.STRING2,
    CONNECTOR.STRING3,
    CONNECTOR.STRING4,
    CONNECTOR.JODA_TIME_DATETIME.convertFrom(d -> dateTimeToInstant(d)))
    .from(CONNECTOR)
    .fetchInto(JsonConnector.class);
```

Comment: thank you very much, and thanks for very powerful jooq